# Dedicated spring boot actuator URL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

**Context :**

Spring boot 2.7.4

**Configuration tried (beyond several) :**

```
management:
  server:
    port: 8080
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: "/monitoring"
      exposure:
        include: "*"
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /myapp
```

**What I try to get :**

get two different URL :

http://localhost:8080/myapp
returns "hello world"

http://localhost:8080/monitoring
returns actuator

**What I get :**

HTTP ERROR 401

I've tried so many different configurations, but I wonder what I missed. Do you know where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actuator is part of the application, therfore it is in the same context which you define beyond spring app - servlet - and this now works for your `http://localhost:8080/myapp/monitoring`

To do what you want, you can for example, in controller classes you can use `@RequestMapping("myapp")` to have your paths prefixed and leave `context-path` as `/` (or ommit it from your configuration);